# Print-out Page Setup Makes Content too Small

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to print out the content of an active worksheet.

The page setup I wrote in VBA.

```
Sub Macro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Reports").Columns("F").Hidden = True
Worksheets("Reports").Columns("R").Hidden = True
Worksheets("Reports").Range("H:J,M:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Dim PrintThis As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("G" & Sheets("Reports").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set PrintThis = Sheets("Reports").Range("F1" & ":T" & LastRow)

With Sheets("Reports").PageSetup
   .Orientation = xlLandscape
   .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
   .PrintArea = "$F:$T"
   .Zoom = False
   .FitToPagesWide = 1
   .FitToPagesTall = False
   .CenterHeader = "Report"
   .CenterFooter = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy")
   .RightFooter = "&P"
End With

PrintThis.PrintPreview

Worksheets("Reports").Columns("F").Hidden = False
Worksheets("Reports").Columns("R").Hidden = False
Worksheets("Reports").Range("H:J,M:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

The code shrinks the content, fitting it into half of the width of a landscape page. I didn't set up FitToPageTall, because the content's length may change depending on other execution in the worksheet. I used the first row as the print title. I hid several columns in the process since they were not needed in the report, but their widths still took the space on the page.

Comment: You don't want to use `PrintTitleColumns`. Use a `PrintArea` to specify the range to print.

Comment: @Rory, I meant PrintArea = "$F:$T"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant do you mean that to replace *PrintTitleColumns* With *PrintArea = "$F:$T"*?

Comment: Yes. You can just try it and see... ;)

Comment: @Rory, It didn't work, it is still very small

Comment: Did you clear the print titles that the code had previously set?

Comment: @Rory, yes I did, but in this way, how does it assign the first row as the title for each page?

Comment: You leave the `PrintTitleRows` in, but clear the `PrintTitleColumns`.

Comment: @Rory, no , it doesn't work

Comment: Ah - I was seeing things. You need to add `.FitToPagesTall = False` after the `FitToPagesWide`. I thought that was already there.

Comment: @Rory, I added it back in there, but it still doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean "added it back" - you never actually had it. Please update the code in the question to show what you have now.

Comment: @Rory, I did actually have it, but someone told me on another forum to take it off, because the statement needs to be a number.

Comment: No, it doesn't - that's only if you want to scale using it. You need it in there.

Comment: Please Check the updated code @Rory.

Comment: I see you deleted your last question but as I mentioned previously, set a number to the property.

Comment: But as @Rory told me here it could be false in the FitToPagesTall statement.@findwindow

Comment: My point is, you could be done with this already if you just set a number XD Computers like to be told exactly what to do. Be specific.

Comment: @findwindow, i tried it, it didnt work.

Comment: What does `didn't work` mean? It printed 100000 pages?

Comment: @findwindow, it means it didn't solve the problem, the content is still very small, only fitting to half of the landscape page.

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: @findwindow, it depends, since it the content varies depending on other executions on the worksheet. But no more than 5000

Comment: Ok so suppose you want 50 rows per page, what happens when you set it to 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per all my previous comments, the code should look like this:

```
Sub Macro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Reports").Columns("F").Hidden = True
Worksheets("Reports").Columns("R").Hidden = True
Worksheets("Reports").Range("H:J,M:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True


Dim PrintThis As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("G" & Sheets("Reports").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set PrintThis = Sheets("Reports").Range("F1" & ":T" & LastRow)

  With Sheets("Reports").PageSetup
   .Orientation = xlLandscape
   .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
   .PrintTitleColumns = ""
   .PrintArea = "$F:$T"
   .FitToPagesWide = 1
   .FitToPagesTall = False
   .Zoom = False
   .CenterHeader = "Report"
   .CenterFooter = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy")
   .RightFooter = "&P"
  End With

PrintThis.PrintPreview

Worksheets("Reports").Columns("F").Hidden = False
Worksheets("Reports").Columns("R").Hidden = False
Worksheets("Reports").Range("H:J,M:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

This is tested and working in 2010 for me.

Comment: It is still only fitting left side of the the page in Excel 2013

Comment: Can you put a workbook somewhere that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Since I am not allowed to share the data, I made a mockup of the original file, it works in the new mockup file... I am very confused now.

Comment: If you replace all the data in a copy of the original file with the word "test" (just do Ctrl=H, enter an asterisk in the Find box and Test in the Replace box, then press Replace All) can you provide the original?

Comment: Sorry, I missed one statement in there. I got it now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to set a printarea as a range name in VBA and to print it. If the worksheet changes, then change the printarea correspondingly. Thus, the idea is to set the [input_print_area] correctly. Usually I use something like this:

```
Public Sub PrintPage()

    Dim Sh                      As Worksheet
    Dim rngPrint                As Range

    On Error GoTo PrintPage_Error
    s_reduce_paper_title = "Go Green!"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = Not tbl_Input.cb_print_color

    Set Sh = ActiveSheet
    Set rngPrint = [input_print_area]

    With Sh.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With

    Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to print?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion Or vbDefaultButton1, s_reduce_paper_title)
    Case vbYes
        Select Case MsgBox("Really sure that you want to print?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion Or vbDefaultButton1, s_reduce_paper_title)
        Case vbYes
            rngPrint.PrintOut
        End Select
    End Select

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

PrintPage_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure PrintPage of Modul mod_Drucken"

End Sub
```

Comment: It's saying there is an error in the 'With Sh,PageSetup' sentence.

Comment: Probably the error is on the line above - you do not have set the range "input_print_area". See how to set range here: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/2011-01-15-excel-range-name-overview.htm